# Can't connect client Mongo with server side

Tags: node.js, mongodb, meteor, ethereum

I'm creating a Meteor App using [this boilerplate](https://github.com/SilentCicero/meteor-dapp-boilerplate).

I'd like to insert some data into MongoDB from the client-side, and then use this data in html files.

However, the Meteor app does not seem to connect client Mongo (minimongo) with server-side (MongoDB). If I try a `{CollectionObj}.insert` command in  the client-side repository, the data does not get written to MongoDB. I checked the collection with `meteor mongo` command, but there is no new data.

So, I wrote the below code on the server-side. (`Contracts` collection is defined in a separate file.)

```
Meteor.methods({
  'insert_contracts': function(address, price, amount, exeday, premium, position, contract_address, abi){
     Contracts.insert({
       seller: address,
       price: price,
       amount: amount,
       exeday: exeday,
       premium: premium,
       position: position,
       contract_address: contract_address,
       abi: abi
     });
  }
});
```

And I wrote this on the client-side:

```
Meteor.call('insert_contracts', address, price, amount, exeday, premium, position, contract_address, abi);
```

So I have implemented an insert function, but I want to change it into a simple implementation using only client-side code.

I also have a problem with the `find` function.

On the server I have tried:

```
'find_contracts': function(){
  return Contracts.find({});
}
```

Then called it from client-side:

```
'click .btn-success': function(event) {
   var hoge = Meteor.call('find_contracts');
```

But `hoge` was stil undefined.

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: If you want to affect server-side database from the client-side, then check out [`allow`](http://docs.meteor.com/#/full/allow) and [`deny`](http://docs.meteor.com/#/full/deny). Otherwise, using a method is your best (and most secure) bet.

Comment: Thank you. If I use `find` command in clien-side also, do I have to allow in server-side? if so, how can I write it?

Comment: In case of `find` queries, you need to [`publish`](http://docs.meteor.com/#/full/meteor_publish) them from the server-side and [`subscribe`](http://docs.meteor.com/#/full/meteor_subscribe) them from the client-side.